# iphone - animate a view to a new width and height

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, transform

The following animates a view to the upper left part of the screen (ipad):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"anim" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    someView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

However, it does not resize the view (think of a UIImageView that I want to blow up). I assume I have to do that with a transform somehow, but all I can figure out how to do is scale, rotation, and translation (CGAffineTransformMakeRotation, CGAffineTransformMakeScale, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation)

How do you transform a view to a specific rectangle? I don't want just a scale up. I need to stretch it to 1024x768, regardless of the intitial size.

Answer (score 0):

Every `UIView` contains a **[CoreAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)** object (**[CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)**), which is used for explicit animations:

Get rid of all the `-beginAnimations` etc calls and just use this:

```
someView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm getting this though:
error: accessing unknown  'bounds' component of a property

Comment: [someView.layer setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
Still just moves it up to the upper left. Doesn't blow it up :(

Answer (score 0):

What is your view contentMode set to?  You should try setting it to this:

```
someView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Edit: Make sure you do this before the animation block.  You should set it in Interface Builder or in the one the view loading methods: loadView or viewDidLoad.